# setListAdapter doesn't display my String-array in the ListActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, render, listactivity

list_item.xml: http://pastebin.com/bn56L3NN

What happens after onCreate() and after creating the Comm-object is that I get a "Connection established" message which gets picked up in another thread and I get the message in receiveMessage, I then send "list" and get called back to receiveMessage again.

I've checked with Log.v and I do get back the message that I want to list, my problem is that I can't display it in the ListActivity when I get to these lines, maybe I should replace them with something else?:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, userRooms));
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Full code:

```
package elf.app;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import elf.app.comm.CommClient;
import elf.app.comm.CommListener;
import elf.app.entity.ELFList;
import elf.app.entity.Entry;

public class RoomListActivity extends ListActivity implements CommListener {
    private ELFList eList;
    private String[] userRooms;
    private CommClient comm;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        eList = new ELFList();
        comm = new CommClient(  getIntent().getExtras().getString("ip"),
                                getIntent().getExtras().getInt("port") );
        comm.setListener(this);
        new Thread(comm).start();
    }

    public void receiveMessage(String IP, String message, int id) {
        if(message.equals("Connection established")) {
            comm.send("list");
        }
        if(message.charAt(0)=='#') {
            String[] strArr = toStringarr(message);
            eList.add(strArr);
            listItems();
        }
    }

    public String[] toStringarr(String str) {
        String substr = str.substring(1);
        return substr.split("@");
    }

    public void listItems() {
        userRooms = eList.returnNames();

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, userRooms));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Entry e = eList.getEntry(position);
                String roominfo = e.toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(RoomListActivity.this, RoomInfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("entry",roominfo);
                intent.putExtra("ip", getIntent().getExtras().getString("ip"));
                intent.putExtra("port", getIntent().getExtras().getInt("port"));
                comm.disconnect();
                RoomListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: ok, added the code into the question now, altho I'm not sure how to format (I've checked the FAQ but for some reason it doesn't work..).
Also, pastebin is an accepted way of pasting larger snippets of text, so I'd recommend splitting code and linking like that.. but I get your point.. I'll post the code directly next time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set a content view for your `Activity` in `onCreate()` which contains the layout for the `Activity`. So there is no list to display which could display anything. Define a layout in a layout XML file and set it as content view using [`setContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29).

Comment: I extend ListActivity so I don't have to, unless I've overlooked something.

Comment: Oh ok, you're right. I never read the documentation for it as I always used it with a custom layout. Have you checked the userRooms variable before you pass it to the adapter whether it contains items?

Comment: Yes, I've changed some code now and it does, I'm getting Runtime and Nullpointer exceptions..


EDIT: here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/sFdNsqP1

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the exception to you question?

Comment: did this: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, strTemp));